# Getting a list of coefficient/exponent pairs in sympy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I have a product of sums that contains powers with real numbered exponents. After successfully expanding this product as a sum of weighted powers (so it is *almost* a polynomial):

```
0.001953125*z**(7/4) + 0.013671875*z**(5/4) + 0.025390625*z**(3/4) +...
```

I tried to get the list of coefficients and exponents out of it. `Poly()` does not seem to work because of the non integer exponents.

Here is how I created the expression:

```
from __future__ import division
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
N=3
Pb = 0.25
z,i=sp.symbols('z, i')
G_F = sp.product((1-Pb+Pb/2*(z**(-2**-i)+z**(+2**-i))), (i,0, N-1))
G_F = G_F.expand().as_expr()
```

I found two not really satisfying ways to get those values. The first way is a list comprehension that got ugly because `sympy` seems to provide an inconsistent expression tree, meaning that the paths downwards to an atom can be `Add->Mul->Pow->Rational` or `Add->Float` or ...

```
[(coeff,e, )
    for addand in G_F.args
        for coeff, zterm in [addand.args or (float(addand),z**0)]
            for _, e in [zterm.args or (None, (zterm))]
]
```

Out:

```
[(0.421875, 1), (0.0820312500000000, 1/2), ... ,(0.00195312500000000, 7/4), (0.0703125000000000, z)]
```

Almost the same thing as a loop:

```
result = []
for addend in G_F.args:
    if isinstance(addend,(sp.Mul)):
        coeff, zterm = addend.args
        if isinstance(zterm, sp.Pow):
            result.append((coeff.evalf(), zterm.args[1].evalf()))
        else:
            result.append((coeff.evalf(), zterm.evalf()))
    else:
        result.append((coeff.evalf(), 0))
result
```

Out:

```
[(0.0703125000000000, 0), (0.0820312500000000, 0.500000000000000), (0.0117187500000000, -1.50000000000000),...  (0.0703125000000000, z)]
```

But both approaches have there pitfalls. I do not get proper python floats and as you can see there are still `z`s in the resulting array.

Is there a (more) generic way to get a list (or `numpy` array) out of such a almost polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you might be able to combine `as_coeff_exponent` and `as_ordered_terms`, and get away with

```
[[float(x) for x in term.as_coeff_exponent(z)] for term in G_F.as_ordered_terms()]
```

which gives me

```
>>> terms = [[float(x) for x in term.as_coeff_exponent(z)] for term in G_F.as_ordered_terms()]
>>> terms.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> terms
[[0.001953125, -1.75], [0.01171875, -1.5], [0.013671875, -1.25], [0.0703125, -1.0], [0.025390625, -0.75], [0.08203125, -0.5], [0.083984375, -0.25], [0.421875, 0.0], [0.083984375, 0.25], [0.08203125, 0.5], [0.025390625, 0.75], [0.0703125, 1.0], [0.013671875, 1.25], [0.01171875, 1.5], [0.001953125, 1.75]]
```